# How can i toggle table tr with jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I create this table with razor in asp.net mvc:

```
...some code...
                @{
                    int counter = 0;
                    foreach (var item in ViewBag.CdrDetail)
                    {
                        counter++;

                        <tr class="success" id=@counter>
                            <td>@counter</td>
                            <td>@item.calledCity</td>
                            <td>@item.Duration</td>
                            <td>@item.Price</td>
                            <td>@item.persianDate</td>
                            <td>@item.perianTime</td>
                            <td>@item.strDestination</td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                }
...some code...
```

and write this jquery code for toggle tr with id:

```
$('#UL li').click(function (e) {
                alert(this.id);
                for (i = this.id; i < $("#MaxValue").val() ; i++) {

                    $('#CDRTABLE .'+i).toggle();
                }
            });
```

but don't toggle ,how can i solve that problem?thanks

Comment: Please post your full HTML code.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai this is my full html code:https://codeshare.io/5wndMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused between [Class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [ID](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) selectors:

In your code for the table rows you are setting the `id` property through `id=@counter` (whihc is a bad idea and semantically very wrong), while in your JS code you are using class selector `$('#CDRTABLE .'+i).toggle(); // see that .`

So, either change your html code to be `class="success @counter"`

OR, change your JS code to be `$('#CDRTABLE #'+i).toggle(); // # not .`

Comment: Ok change to class="success @counter" so how can write toggle in jquery for that purpose?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi , I understand that you need to toggle the visibility for your table rows. so your `click()` should work properly now

Comment: change my code to class="success @counter"  now need to change toggle code ,how can write toggle code in jquery for class="success @counter"?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi , why the need to change the toggle code? Isn't your problem that the `click` do nothing(due to wrong selector)?

Comment: `$('#CDRTABLE #' + i.toString()).toggle();` .. you forgot the **#**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133194/discussion-between-ebram-khalil-and-behzad-razzaqi).